# install mysql in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I had Ubuntu 10.04 installed.

To install MySQL, I had downloaded:

mysql-5.1.57-linux-i686-glibc23.tar.gz

and

mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-1ubu1004-i386.deb.

I cannot download from the linux system.

My Question is whether these two files install

MySQL Server and MySQL GUI

on the linux system.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install mysql run `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1` its a quick and easiest way